# Rails transform variable name and value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, backwards-compatibility

I want to use a transformed name/value in the property of a class than we get from the database. The reason I need this is I have two versions of an app that points to the same database, but the newer version recently updated the column name. So, for all apps that use the older version it has to be made compatible.

```
Environment: Rails version: 6.0.3.3 & Ruby version: ruby 2.7.1p83
```

Suppose there is class called ***Sprinter***.
Sprinter table looks like:

| id | name | m | s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr. Bolt | 100 | 9.58 |

A sprinter instance would look like:

```
sprinter = {
   "id" => 1,
   "name" => "Mr. Bolt",
   "m" => 100,
   "s" => 9.58
}
```

The older version expects a different format. Now I want to have something like:

```
sprinter = {
   "id" => 1,
   "name" => "Mr. Bolt",
   "cm" => 10000, # transformed from `m`
   "ms" => 9580   # transformed from `s`
}
```

The `m` column name has been transformed to `cm` and the value has been transformed too. Same case for `s` to `ms`. The value transformation is not a big deal, but the variable name seems to be.

I'd prefer an internal update when I fetch the object. However if that's not supported, as a base-level solution, I'd prefer to change the json representation that I sent to the client. For reference, I use it as part of nested `include` like:

```
render status: :ok, json: {races: races}.as_json(
            {:include => [:sprinters] }
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How you'll be able to check whether the API call has been made from the apps which use the old version or the new version?

Comment: Well, the url will have /api/v100/... and /api/v101/... And based on that, the request will route to the specific server that can handle that request.

Comment: great that means there are separate controllers for that? right?

Comment: Yep, you could say that. I'm planning to support v100 (old) just for a few weeks so will have running it in a different server, and ditch it completely in the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mucking about with the internals of `.as_json` or how your model does serialization you can use a serialization layer instead to handle different representations of your model in JSON.

For example you can use [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or JBuilder or even roll your own if thats your deal.

```
module API
  module V2
    class SprinterAdapter
      def intialize(sprinter)
        @sprinter = sprinter
      end

      def to_json
        @sprinter.to_json.except("m", "s").merge(
          "cm" => @sprinter.m * 100,
          "ms" => @sprinter.s * 1000
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in your controller you would use the serializer to render the resource:

```
module API
  module V2
    class SprintersController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @sprinter = Sprinter.find(params[:id])
        render json: SprinterAdapter.new(@sprinter)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See:

- [Thoughtbot: Better serialization, less as_json](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json)
- [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/API_Builders)

Comment: Note that this is not really meant as an actual copy-paste solution - its more of a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Yep, this looks like an elegant solution for a straightforward object representative. But, when I generate the json, the `sprinter` object is a nested attribute. It is joined with a `:include` to the parent one. I feel like this won't fix that.

Comment: That's where a gem like AMS comes in. It will use serializers for associations as well.

Comment: That looks like a handy tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform keys/values by [select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) from `Sprinter`:

```rb
Sprinter.select(:id, :name, 'm * 100 AS cm', 's * 1000 AS ms')
```

But not sure how to combine it with [as_json](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

Comment: This looks like a start. Is there a way to modify the default behavior when we do stuff life.. `race.sprinter`. I'd like the model to always return the transformed version.